# Safe Sinks js confusion

Tags: xss, javascript

Have some confusion regarding [safe sinks](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#safe-sinks) in javascript.

The DOMpurify library linked in the OWASP article does not explicitly mention the `.files` and `.valueAsDate` of an HTMLInputElement as safe sinks, but the more common `.value` is a safe sink. I was wondering if these are safe sinks and how to tell if some property/function is a safe sink other than referring to some third party list?